# Kubernetes OutOfCPU scenario

Tags: kubernetes

In OutOfCPU scenarios scheduler keeps on scheduling the pod to same node and somewhere 1000+ same pod scheduled on the node with OOC, Scheduler should check the resources of node before scheduling isn't the behavior.

Checked scheduler logs, it keeps on scheduling whereas from journalctl logs says "node didn't have enough resource" then why scheduler scheduling the same.

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is.

Comment: Kubelet is rejecting the request as it didn't have enough resource but scheduler keep on scheduling the pod to same node.